# Lua separate functions at different intervals

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Specifically I am trying to write a simple script for a Logitech mouse that uses Lua language.

The desired script is straightforward: Move the mouse down 1 pixel every 5 milliseconds and click mouse button 1 every 500 milliseconds.

The actions independent of each other are easy;

```
repeat
MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
Sleep (5)

repeat
PressMouseButton(1)
Sleep (500)
```

However, I am looking for a simple/elegant way to combine them into one loop. Any suggestions for a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the straightforward variant could be:

```
repeat
  for i=1,100 do
    MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
    Sleep(5)
  end
  PressMouseButton(1)
until false
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad, I think this will work for my purpose. Now I just need to learn about coroutines so that I can break the loop when needed.

Comment: Does LGS even support coroutines?

Comment: A quick test reveals that it does. However, using coroutines may not be what I want. I want to be able to break the script before it completes, and then start the script from the beginning again. From my limited understanding, it sounds like coroutines would resume the script from where it left off?

Comment: @shiphtfour To end the script you can just `return` from it on some condition. Coroutines are needed if you need to resume the execution from the point where you've yielded. If you just need to break script and start from the beginning, then simple return is enough.

Comment: @Vlad thank you again. If I may trouble you one more time, how would that look in code? Let's say I want the loop to continue as long as the condition `loop == 1`. If `loop == 0`, then I want the loop to break. If using `return` to achieve this, can the loop break before it completes? For instance, can I break the loop before `i=100`?

Comment: @shiphtfour I'm not familiar with LGS, so can't tell if that condition could be altered from outside _while_ your script is running. Probably you'll need to call some function to check external events (button/key state, etc) to decide if script should terminate. Normally you can't expect that some variable would be updated without you passing control back to hosting application in some way.